# ZF2 - Convert select statement to query using getSqlStringForSqlObject gives warning

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want to convert $sql->select() statement to string. I tried

```
$sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select)
```

and also

```
$select->getSqlString($this->_dbAdapter->getPlatform())
```

but it gives warning

> Notice: Attempting to quote a value in Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\Oracle
>   without extension/driver support can introduce security
>   vulnerabilities in a production environment.

I dont want to supress the warning I want to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It works without errors

```
$adapter = GlobalAdapterFeature::getStaticAdapter();
$sql = new Sql($adapter);
$select = $sql->select();
...
$queryString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);
```